# How to import JSON Array to Google Sheet using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script, rows

I try to import data from http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees to sheet via google script app. But I have problem "Node not available"

I try to use :

```
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){

  try{
    // /rates/EUR
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);

    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    //Logger.log(patharray);

    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }

    //Logger.log(typeof(json));

    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];[enter image description here][1]

      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }

}
```

Comment: Might want to take a look into this tutorial: 
This apporach is without google script though. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVBsnN31yHI

Comment: "Node Not Available" is the message implemented in your code in case the variable json is not an object. There might be an error the url fetch so the response is empty or does not feature the expected format. I recommend you to log `res`,`content` and `json` (the latter both before and after the for loop) to troubleshoot.